# Detect whether code is running as part of a Spring-based application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library which is usually built into third-party software as a component. There is another library which adds Spring support for the main library in case it runs within Spring, where some things such as database connections are handled differently.

What I want to do is make sure that when the main library is running as part of a Spring-based application, the helper library is also present. So I need to somehow detect whether the application the library is running in is Spring-based or not. What would be a sane approach to this?

I have an idea which might work, which is to check that some part of Spring core is present, like this:

```
boolean isSpringApplication = false;
boolean isSpringSupportPresent = false;

// Check Spring
try {
   Class.forName("org.springframework.some.core.Class");
   isSpringApplication = true;
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // This is fine
}

// Check Spring Support Lib
try {
   Class.forName("org.mylibrary.spring.support.Class");
   isSpringSupportPresent = true;
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // This is fine
}

if (isSpringApplication && !isSpringSupportPresent) {
    LOGGER.error("Application is running within Spring but the Spring Support Library is not present.");
}
```

**Is this a reasonable approach to the problem? If so, what would be the best Spring class to check for?**

Comment: That doesn't sound reasonable to me. Does the support library contain Spring beans?

Comment: @daniu It does not. But even if it did, we're trying to detect this when running outside of Spring, so directly referencing anything Spring-related is not an option as it would make the library itself depend on Spring.

Comment: Checking for the presence of libraries / classes as you outlined is the standard approach. Spring does it like that too. I would try to load one of the Spring classes that you absolutely need, just a reminder: Spring isn't just Spring web. If all you want to know if there is an ApplicationContext maybe check  for the classes presence or some other fundamental class like the annotation class `@Component` for spring context

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable. Just check for ApplicationContext.